# Why training time of each loop is slow when set `scale_pos_weight = 15` in XGBoost?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I follow the [param tuning skilss](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243207/what-is-the-proper-usage-of-scale-pos-weight-in-xgboost-for-imbalanced-datasets) and set `scale_pos_weight = count(negative examples)/count(Positive examples)`.
But training time of each loop is slower than before.
And I check the [original code](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/4224c08cacceba3f83f90e387c07aa6205a83bfa/plugin/updater_oneapi/regression_obj_oneapi.cc) but did not find the proper reasons, which seems to only multiple a weight on a positive label weight.

```
if (label == 1.0f) {
    w *= scale_pos_weight;
}
```